# using codeigniter export pdf files from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

using codeigniter I create a form where i insert data into MySQL database. After complete insert i want to retrieve data as PDF file.

In modeld my file name- membership_model.php.
In view page I have form name- send_form.php
but after send data i have a successful page name **signup_successful.php** here is a link **export as pdf** button who call **topdf()** in login page. but is doesn't work. please help in topdf function.

in view folder- signup_successful.php

```
<p>Your data has been sent. 
<?php echo anchor('topdf', 'Export as PDF');?>
</p>
```

controllers folder

login.php

```
<?php

class Login extends Controller {

    function index()
    {
       parent::Controller();
           $this->load->helper('pdf_helper');
    }


    function data_info()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'data_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

    function sent_data()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        $this->load->view('data_form');
        }
        else
        {           
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        if($query = $this->membership_model->send_data())
               //create_member call model create_member
        {
           $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
           $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('data_form');
            }
         }  
    }

    function topdf () 
    {
       $this->load->library('cezpdf');
       $this->load->helper('pdf_helper');
       prep_pdf();
       $data['member']= $this->membership_model->alldata();
       $titlecolumn = array(
                'first-name' => 'First-name',
                'last_name' => 'Last_name',
                'email_address' => 'Email_address'
                       );
       $this->cezpdf->ezTable($data['member'], $titlecolumn,'Member Data');
       $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but is doesn't work"* won't fly here. Be more specific.

Comment: So there are no errors and it's broken?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any info on what is not working and what does your cezpdf library do I can only say that your code

```
<?php echo anchor('topdf', 'Export as PDF');?>
```

is calling the wrong method, unless you have some routing you didn't tell us. To call the topdf() method in your controller you need to use:

```
<?php echo anchor('login/topdf', 'Export as PDF');?>
```

I'm waiting for more info to go on guessing.

Comment: I call data from database this function-- function alldata()
    {
     $q = $this->db->get('membership');
  
     if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
      foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
       $data[] = $row;
      }
      return $data;
     }
     
    } but main problem is topdf().

Comment: @Arifkarim Did you correct the anchor() function? Have you tried removing the call to the cezpdf library, to see if the problem lies there or not?